# Shortest path algorithm for a huge bus route database

Tags: database, algorithm, search, shortest-path

I am building a bus routes map for Chennai. I use Postgis. In our database we have one table having all the routes along with unique ids given for them. Second table comprises of bus stop names with its latitude and longitudes. The third table joins the first and second table based on their ids. We have track records for the routes.

I want to construct a function for finding the shortest route between 2 stops which don’t have a common route. For eg, Two stops A and B exist which don’t have any common routes. Say there are 3 other stops- C,D,E. I want to find out which route should I take to travel the shortest distance. If I leave from A, should I get off at C and from C take a bus to B, or get off at C take another bus to D and from there another bus to B, or go to E and then take a bus.

Basically I want to find the shortest path for two stops without a common route. Since my database is enormous that needs to be considered while choosing an Algorithm cause it shouldn’t slow down the process.

Could someone please suggest a suitable algorithm which doesn’t take much time?

Comment: This is a straightforward problem on a graph with edge weights.  Shortest path algorithms for such a graph are covered well on Wikipedia and other sites, including many code examples on Stack Overflow.  Where are you stuck in your research?

Comment: Which algorithms have you looked into already. If you are strictly asking about the algorithm look into https://cs.stackexchange.com If you are looking for help with code please try to solve the issue and asks questions if you get stuck.